# np.where nested conditions on dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe named histdf like the following. I want to add a new column name 'Side' with the following conditions :

Calculate the price difference between the priceAsk and the priceBid.

If the price is greater than the average of the PriceAsk + PriceBid + 10% of price difference : side should be ask

if the average is less than than the average of the PriceAsk + PriceBid - 10% of price difference : side should be bid

| Price | priceBid | PriceAsk | Side |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.95 | 0.75 | 1.25 | should be bid |
| 1.05 | 0.75 | 1.25 | should be ask |
| 0.96 | 0.75 | 1.25 | should be mid |
| 1.00 | 0.75 | 1.25 | should be mid |
| 1.04 | 0.75 | 1.25 | should be mid |

Here is my failed attemp. Can you please help me with the appropriate code?

```
histdf['Side'] = np.where(histdf['price'] < (((histdf['priceBid'] + histdf['priceAsk']) // 2) - (0.1 * ((histdf['priceBid'] + histdf['priceAsk']) // 2))) , 'BID', \
                np.where(histdf['price'] > (((histdf['priceBid'] + histdf['priceAsk']) // 2) + (0.1 * ((histdf['priceBid'] + histdf['priceAsk']) // 2))) , 'ASK', 'MID'))`
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the quick reply.

You were missing the Mid in your answer, but you pointed me in the good direction.

Here is what I ended up coding. I'm still open to hear from the community if there is cleaner way to do this :

```
histdf['Mid']= (histdf['priceAsk'] + histdf['priceBid']) / 2.0
histdf['BidAskSpread']=histdf['priceAsk']-histdf['priceBid']
histdf['Side']=np.where(histdf['price'] <= (histdf['Mid'] - (0.1 * histdf['BidAskSpread'])), 'Bid',np.where(histdf['price'] >= (histdf['Mid'] + (0.1 *histdf['BidAskSpread'])), 'Ask', 'Mid'))
```